# Regex expression in C# to match "..."

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find and remove any occurence of "..." in various strings in a C# program. Either side of the "..." can be absolutely anything, but it is never at the beginning or end of the string.

I have tried "\.{3}", "[\.]{3}" and ""(\.\.\.)". None of these seem to work.

Anybody know what's wrong?

### EDIT

Fixed. What I thought was "..." was actually "…". It was a single character I was trying to match.

Comment: Within you IDEs search & replace function or by code?

Comment: I'm trying to rename a big batch of files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply use

```
string result = source.Replace("...", "");
```

Comment: . = any character, so won't that match any three characters?

Comment: @Luke Replace doesn't use RegEx.

Comment: "." is any character in Regex, not in `String.Replace`

Comment: OH. I see. I have been using Regex.Replace... so got confused.

Comment: Worked. Turns out the ellipsis was an ellipsis character, and not three fullstops.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered just using the String.Replace method? It may be quicker than a regex.

```
string s = "weioufhw...wefwef...wefwef...wefwef...";
string newS = s.Replace("...","");
```

Comment: It must work, unless we've misunderstood the problem. Are you looking for `...` or `"..."` with the double quotes? If it's just `...` then it DOES work!

Comment: Thanks, it does work. I was just being silly, it's an ellipsis character in the string, not three fullstops.

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten to escape your escape. Use either `"\\.{3}"` or `@"\.{3}"`.

Answer (score 1):

To achive your goal may the best way is the [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) method

You can use on a string like this:

```
string testString = "...a...b...c...";
string resultString = testString.Replace("...","");
```

The result should be simple "abc".

Answer (score 0):

Just do search and replace (Ctrl + h) and fill in the "..." in the find field and make sure the replace field is empty and then choose the option to replace in all files or only the current.

Answer (score 0):

this would work if you really wanted to use regex

```
        private void Test()
    {
        string regex = "\\.{3}";
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions options = ((System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline) 
                    | System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(regex, options);
    }
```

Comment: You've specified three regex options that will do nothing in this case. They just add noise to the code and thus make it harder to understand.